# What's the meaning of “to him who”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

While I was searching on the net, I found this  sentence:

> Memorandum to him who is concerned.

I looked for a definition to *to him who*, but I found nothing. So what's the meaning of it?

ِAre these two sentences equivalent:

- Memorandum for those who are concerned.
- Memorandum to him who is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To him who" is not a phrase, and therefore hasn't a definition.

"Who is concerned" is a relative clause, modifying "him".

Having said that, I can't imagine a native English speaker saying or writing this: it is quite unnatural. It sounds to me like somebody half-remembering the formulaic salutation (at the top of a letter or notice):

> To whom it may concern

This, again, is grammatical, but would not be natural modern English, if it were not preserved as a (written) idiom.

Comment: I fondly relish the thought of someday receiving a letter whose salutation reads *“To anybody who cares,”* at the top — and with a comma instead of a colon, too. Alas, the Plain English movement may never get that far, but one can always hope.